# MySQL LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE cuts umlauts and ß

Tags: mysql, xml, load-data-infile, xml-import

I'm importing large xml files with german address into mysql. the problem is records are getting cut from umlaut/special character. For example for "München" I get "M" and "Straße" -> "Stra" imported
table has 'utf8_general_ci' collation. I import from windows share in my ubuntu vm
start mysql:

```
mysql --local-infile -uroot -p
```

are any collation parameters necessary?

I tryed this in mysql shell:

```
charset utf8;
```

and here my sql:

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.56.1,share=movieapp/Kinoprogramm/AdressenGeo.xml' INTO TABLE adresse CHARACTER SET 'utf8' ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Adresse>';
```

Answer (score 0):

figured out xml was not unicode but cp1252, so changed

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.56.1,share=movieapp/Kinoprogramm/AdressenGeo.xml' INTO TABLE adresse CHARACTER SET 'utf8' ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Adresse>';
```

to

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE '/run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=192.168.56.1,share=movieapp/Kinoprogramm/AdressenGeo.xml' INTO TABLE adresse CHARACTER SET 'latin1' ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<Adresse>';
```

and now everything works